# How to Grab newly created PK and return page of that selected index

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor, scope-identity

I have an MVC 4 Application, VS 2010, Entity Framework 5, Sql 2008 R2, c#

In my controller, after I add a new entry (which is really a form to add to a dropdownlist), I want to grab the ID just created and pass that back to the dropdownlist so the page now shows the newly created entry (and all its details).

I keep reading about SCOPE IDENTITY, but I'm not sure how to implement and use it (if its possible) from this side. Any suggestions are most welcome.

```
public ActionResult Create(x y)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.x.Add(y);
            db.SaveChangesNew();

            //select id from x where id = scope_identity();     ???
           // int ID = (int)db.ExecuteScalar();                 ???
          //  Select @@IDENTITY as newId;                       ???
           // SELECT NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();                  ???

         // ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.x, "ID", "Name", y); ???

            return View();


        }
```

Answer (score 2):

After `SaveShanges()` id of newly added record is automatically added by **EF** in the object which we add, you can confirm by debugging and watching:

```
db.x.Add(y);
db.SaveChangesNew();

int InsertedRecordId = y.Id;
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe that was so simple. But how to I pass it pack to the view which contains the dropdownlist?

Comment: `db.x` will fetch the newly added record as well

Comment: thanks alot! But how to I pass it pack to the view which contains the dropdownlist?

Comment: your question is not clear you want to pass data to which view?

Comment: to the index view associated with that page. usually its done like  return RedirectToAction("Index"); however the only thing on that Index page is a dropdown list (the id of which just caught above) i need to pass - because I want that upon entry of the details and i click save, it should navigate to the index page, but with the dropdown list value selected as the id. better?

Comment: ``ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.x, "ID", "Name", y);`` this did'nt worked for you?